# UICollectionView : After reload didSelectItem not called

Tags: uicollectionview

Whenever I reload a UICollectionView twice , didSelectItemAtIndexPath is not called for some cells.

I am testing on iOS 9.3

Comment: there are issues with collectionview in ios 9.3